# two password for one username in Symfony2

Tags: php, authentication, symfony, passwords

For a project, we need to give access to a user with 2 password. One is the user's password, the second will be a temporary password to give access to the account by an administrator.

After many researches, we didn't find how to do that. The auth process is handled by the core of Symfony2, in this file : [DaoAuthenticationProvider.php](http://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/DaoAuthenticationProvider.php#L54)

Does someone have an idea to help us ? We try looking in the FOSUserBundle but it's using Symfony2 to auth an user too ...

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally we found an other way to solve our issue. We wanted to be able to get access to an user without having his password.

And we found in the Symfony 2 documentation the impersonating function which can give access to an user only by passing the username in the URL with the parameter **_switch_user**

For more information take a look here :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#impersonating-a-user

Comment: Since you unaccepted your answer - you could at least upvote mine

Answer (score 1):

You have to define your [own Authentication Provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html#the-authentication-provider), your [Factory](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html#the-factory) and [inject it into your security](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html#configuration).

Check that links - they clarify everything you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm not sure how to override the process which check the entered password with the password stored in the database. The FOSUserBundle is an User Provider but there is nothing like that, and I'm a little lost. The process I want to change is here (but I have no idea how to override it) : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/DaoAuthenticationProvider.php#L54

Comment: @Nanaki please, post your `security.yml` contents and I'll help you to redefine that behavior ;)

Comment: I have no idea how it could solve my problem, but here it is :

This is my security.yml before adding the FOSUserBundle :
[link](http://pastebin.com/v36cmKT9)

And after adding the FOSUserBundle :
[link](http://pastebin.com/2YgBT4n4)

Comment: @Nanaki Edited my answer - please, check. You have to write your own Authentication Provider, define `checkAuthentication()` method there and inject it via factory to your security.